# While using the vexana package in Flutter, I create my own Error Model, but I am getting errors

Tags: flutter

The error model I created does not handle or parse the data, it constantly returns null. However, the api response comes successfully in the `response.data.description` statement. What is the solution?

I reviewed the YouTube video created by Veli Bacik and when I watch it up to the current time in the link I shared, it works without any problems. It doesn't work in my code, I don't understand. I would appreciate it if you could help me fix the mistake I made. :)

[Network Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T144W.png)

[Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHkuX.png)

[Err Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90sC7.png)

[Login Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHW8D.png)

[Base Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpZro.png)

[Github link of my project](https://github.com/mucahitsimsek/food_fiesta)

[Veli Bacik Vexana](https://youtu.be/5dm2M0GGEcE?t=3608)

When I use EmptyModel the model comes up as null. What could be the reason for null on any of my models?